# Typescript - Property is missing in type implementing an interface, even though the property is defined

Tags: typescript

In one of my ts modules, I have an interface defined, with a class that implements it like so (cleaned for brevity):

```
export interface Encoder {
    name: string;
    exec: (str: string, origParam?: string | null) => string;
}

class NOPEncoder implements Encoder {
    public name: "None";
    public exec(str: string, origParam?: string | null): string {
        // origParam is not important in this case, this method is designed as a no-op
        return str;
    }
}
```

However, trying to create a `Map<string, Encoder>` is giving me some problems. I've tried both of these methods of constructing a value of said type:

```
// Method 1
const encoders = new Map<string, Encoder>();
encoders.set("NOP", NOPEncoder);

// Method 2
const encoders = new Map<string, Encoder> ([
    ["NOP", <Encoder>NOPEncoder],
]);
```

Both method 1 and method 2 give me an error like `"Type 'typeof NOPEncoder' cannot be converted to type 'Encoder'. Property 'exec' is missing in type 'typeof NOPEncoder'."` However, the `NOPEncoder` class explicitly implements the `Encoder` interface (and the compiler is fine with this), and it clearly has an `exec` method. What am I doing wrong here such that the compiler doesn't accept that `NOPEncoder` is coercible into an `Encoder` instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOPEncoder` is a class. You are defining the `Map` as taking an instance of `Encoder`; i.e. the class `NOPEncoder` is not an instance of `Encoder`, it is a type that extends `Encoder`. This should work:

```
const encoders = new Map<string, Encoder>();
encoders.set("NOP", NOPEncoder());
```

If you want to store the actual class reference, I am not currently aware of a way to do this in TypeScript. I would be very interested to learn of a way to do this, if anyone knows!

Edited to add: @jcalz has a close-enough method of storing the signature of the type constructor, as `Map<string, new (...args: any[]) => Encoder>`. Neat trick, I'll have to play around with it sometime!

Comment: Welp, now I just feel stupid. That's obvious in retrospect, thanks.

Comment: FYI, to store class constructors, you would do something like `Map<string, new (...args: any[]) => Encoder>`.  If you want to store only class constructors that take no arguments, you would do `Map<string, new() => Encoder>`.